# Sails.js + ES6 : What is the best architecture?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js, ecmascript-6

I just upgraded from [node](https://nodejs.org/en/) 0.12 to [node](https://nodejs.org/en/) 4.0. I am using [sails.js](http://sailsjs.org/) to build my apps.

With node's new [ES6](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/es6/) support and [sails.js](http://sailsjs.org/), I'm a little confused as to how my folder structure is going to look like? Do I still continue using my `ORM` within the `controllers` or move them to separate layers?

Could someone suggest a good project to which I can refer to, to get the architecture clean with [ES6](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/es6/) and [sails](http://sailsjs.org/)?

Comment: Why do you think the folder structure would / should change?

Answer (score 1):

Your structure remains the same. Just start writing your models/controllers/config/whatever with ES6 syntax and use babel-node for start it. For that install babel as dev dependency and update `npm start` script in `package.json` with `"start": "babel-node app.js"`.

**UPD:** Someone can suggest `sails-hook-babel` but I don't recommend to use it. Hooks have a specific order for loading and you can be confused with ES6 support errors in console, because hook is still not loaded.

Comment: Babel advises against using `babel-node` to run production apps: https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/cli/#babel-node